# Send a private key with JWT

Tags: encryption, jwt

Can I use JWT to exchange a private key ?
I must use this private key to decrypt earlier encrypted data. I use TLS to exchange information between the server and client. Is secure ? It is a valid idea to exchange the key ?
Example:

**Header**

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**Payload**

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "private_key": Base64(generated private key)
}
```

**Signature**

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  passphrase
)
```

Comment: The key is sent from server to client, isn't it? I do not understand why you want to include it in a JWT token instead of a single transmission. For example when the client uses the token to authenticate, it will always send the token and the encryption key, when it is not needed

Comment: Yes this is a special key sent from server to client. I want exchange this key to decrypt a particular content encrypted from another entity.

Comment: @pedrofb generally treat it as confidential content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a secured communication is established, each stakeholder generates/has its own private key. Only public keys are exchanged. Private key exchange should be prevented.

Anyway, if you you really need to send a private key through the JWT format, then you should read about the [JSON Web Key (JWK) specification (RFC7517) section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-7).
The process is quite simple: create a JWE with the JWK as payload and mandatory headers plus the (optional) `cty` header parameter with value `jwk+json`.

Example:

#### JWE Header:

```
{
    "alg":"A256KW",
    "enc":"A256GCM",
    "cty":"jwk+json"
}
```

#### JWE Payload (the JWK):

```
{
    "kty":"oct",
    "alg":"A128KW",
    "k":"GawgguFyGrWKav7AX4VKUg"
}
```

Comment: Can I use JWK to send keys generated with pairing (not RSA, not ECC) ?

Comment: A JWK object is a key. If you want to send a key set (JWKSet) then it is almost the same process, only the header changes (see the section 7)